# Numpy: Change values in numpy array by indexes and condition

Tags: python, numpy

I am new in numpy, and I am having troubles with simple managment of numpy arrays.

I am doing a task in which it said that loops has to be avoid as much as possible, and I need to edit the values of an array through another array of indexes.

```
indexes # [3, 16]
y # [0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
y[indexes] = 2 # [0. 1. 1. 2. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 2. 0. 1. 1.]
```

But I don't need change the value simply by 2. I need make a conditional change. This what I have got, but I would need something like

```
y[indexes] = 0 if y[indexes] == 1 else 0 
>>> [0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1.]
```

And the line above should be the results.

This is the loop way answer, but I need a numpy way if exists:

```
for index in indexes:
    y[index] = 1 if y[index] == 0 else 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your original answer (`y[indexes] = 2`) avoid loops -- what exactly do you need to change about it?

Comment: Because this is not what I need, I need change the value based on a condition, not by 2. For example: `y[indexes] = 1 if y[index] == 0 else 0`, do you understand?

Comment: Are you read the docs for `np.where()`?

Comment: @rahlf23 yes, but I don't know how to introduce the index in the condition

`np.where( [condition based on index of element], indexes, 1 if indexes == 0 else 0 )`

Comment: As @rahfl23 mentioned, `y[indexes] = np.where(y[indexes] == 0, 1, 0)` should work (although you need to convert `y` to an array first: `y = np.array(y)`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question. But I hope this helps you.

## tip 01

```
import numpy as np 
indexes = [1, 5, 7] # index list
y = np.array([9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]) #array example
y[indexes][2] #3rd(0,1,>>2<<) item of y array (1,5,>>7<<).
```

In this case it is y[7] equal 16.

## tip 02

This can also be useful.

```
y = np.array([0,1,1,0,3,0,1,0,1,0])
y
```

array([0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])

```
np.where(y != 1, y, 0)
y
```

array([0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])